# Using Highmaps mapbbuble and datalabels. Datalabels are not going out of screen when zoomed

Tags: javascript, highcharts, highmaps

Using Highmaps, When map bubble and data labels are used together. Zooming into a country still shows the data labels of few other countries in a shabby way(at the bottom of the container). 
I have reproduced the bug here:

> http://jsfiddle.net/q2nxbcee/1/

```
{
    type: 'mapbubble',
    mapData: mapData,
    name: 'Population 2013',
    joinBy: ['iso-a2', 'code'],
    data: data,
    minSize: 4,
    maxSize: '12%',
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '{point.code}: {point.z} thousands'
    },
    dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        //allowOverlap: true,
        formatter: function() {
            if (this.point.value > 0) {
                return this.point.value;
            } else {
                return 10;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Screenshot of the issue:
[image: Data labels are accumulated at the bottom when zoomed in or panned away]

> Observation

The data labels are displayed at the bottom which are labels of some bubbles at the bottom, which must not be showed.

Comment: Hope this may works,
https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/commit/215fdb1a8bf1e1c8329db51ae2446ebd7c1693bd

Comment: That's a committed change. The map.js which I am using has those changes.

Comment: @jeffrycopps So now all works well or not  ? Have you tried workaround from here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/4462 ?

Comment: No, the above issue is quite different from what I am facing.

Comment: The bug you have shown happens in positioning the data labels. Whereas in my case, the positioning is initially correct. Only that,
the labels have to disappear when I zoom in a particular area are still seen at the bottom. The picture and jsfiddle clearly explains the bug. And sorry, the workaround didn't help. But, appreciate your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the provided documentation

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.dataLabels.overflow

you need to add the following attributes to dataLabels

```
dataLabels : {
 overflow: 'none',
 crop:false
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q2nxbcee/2/)